# is it possible to use twitter Bootstrap->front-end + Spring-Hibernate->Backend in a web app that requires storage of session data

Tags: spring, hibernate, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I want to create a web app that uses Twitter Bootstrap for the front end, and the backend uses Spring+Hibernate.

Now, some data has to be stored in each user's session-- how do I store/manage such data?
Do I have to use a 3rd party JS framework like Angular (by Google) or some other framework for this purpose?

Also, in such a hybrid app, should I use the JS framework (like Jquery or Angular JS) for storing the data and then send it to the Spring + Hibernate API? What I mean is, I can as well  store the object-> relational DB mapping in the js framework, and use Spring only for basic database inserts/updates/selects?

Comment: why the down vote? the question is logical, specific and does not ask for conjecture?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use Twitter Bootstrap for the front end, and Spring MVC -> REST API for the back end...

For simple apps, ex search-only apps we can straightaway create an API and use JQuery to connect to the API and fetch data.

For more complex apps, the problem is that REST APIs dont store session data... For this, however we can use Spring MVC-> REST API as that has support specifically to handle sessions.

Refer http://tedyoung.me/2011/10/19/practical-spring-mvc-part-5-sessions/ that explains how to store session data using Spring MVC- and the front end is a simple HTML/CSS web page.

Answer (score 4):

Twitter bootstrap is a CSS framework with some javascript plugins, and is not a language in itself. Using it or not using it will have no impact on what you can/can't use on your backend.

As for sessions; sessions should always be stored server-side... therefore using Bootstrap will have no affect on your implementation of sessions.

Finally, in regards to keeping any of your database logic client side in javascript, NEVER do this. Javascript code can extremely easily be modified by the user, so anything client side should be considered unsecure. Do not ever put anything unsecure in your database.

Comment: please refer http://tedyoung.me/2011/10/19/practical-spring-mvc-part-5-sessions/ that explains how to store session data using Spring MVC- am I correct in thinking that the front end can be a simple web page (for eg using Twitter Bootstrap)--> and the HTML web page simply invokes the REST API-> which uses Spring MVC and can store session data (as shown in the URL above)? Thanks....

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Spring, however this does seem logical. Your front end will always be an HTML page (with javascript most likely), which will communicate with whatever you are running on the server through some mechanism (in this case a RESTful API. Your session data would be store server-side by Spring.

Comment: thanks- i have added the above finding (using Spring MVC for session data handling) as an answer...